# for loop says object not found

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset named trainset and I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate through the specific columns and sums the values up, repeating for all rows in the dataset.

I firstly defined a function to return prediction by calculating the total score:

```
point = 0
m.gwtg = function(Systolic.BP, BUN, Sodium, Age, HR, COPD){
  if (Systolic.BP>=200){
    point = 0
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 190){
    point = 2
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 180){
    point = 4
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 170){
    point = 6
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 160){
    point = 8
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 150){
    point = 9
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 140){
    point = 11
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 130){
    point = 13
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 120){
    point = 15
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 110){
    point = 17
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 100){
    point = 19
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 90){
    point = 21
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 80){
    point = 23
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 70){
    point = 24
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 60){
    point = 26
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 50){
    point = 28
  }
  if (BUN>=150){
    point = point + 28
  }else if (BUN>= 140){
    point = point + 27
  }else if (BUN>= 130){
    point = point + 25
  }else if (BUN>= 120){
    point = point + 23
  }else if (BUN>= 110){
    point = point + 21
  }else if (BUN>= 100){
    point = point + 19
  }else if (BUN>= 90){
    point = point + 17
  }else if (BUN>= 80){
    point = point + 15
  }else if (BUN>= 70){
    point = point + 13
  }else if (BUN>= 60){
    point = point + 11
  }else if (BUN>= 50){
    point = point + 9
  }else if (BUN>= 40){
    point = point + 8
  }else if (BUN>= 30){
    point = point + 6
  }else if (BUN>= 20){
    point = point + 4
  }else if (BUN>= 10){
    point = point + 2
  }else if (BUN<= 9){
    point = point + 0
  }
  if (Sodium>=139){
    point = point + 0
  }else if (Sodium>= 137){
    point = point + 1
  }else if (Sodium>= 134){
    point = point + 2
  }else if (Sodium>= 131){
    point = point + 3
  }else if (Sodium<= 130){
    point = point + 4
  }
  
  if (Age>=110){
    point = point + 28
  }else if (Age>= 100){
    point = point + 25
  }else if (Age>= 90){
    point = point + 22
  }else if (Age>= 80){
    point = point + 19
  }else if (Age>= 70){
    point = point + 17
  }else if (Age>= 60){
    point = point + 14
  }else if (Age>= 50){
    point = point + 11
  }else if (Age>= 40){
    point = point + 8
  }else if (Age>= 30){
    point = point + 6
  }else if (Age>= 20){
    point = point + 3
  }else if (Age<= 19){
    point = point + 0
  }
  
  if (HR>=105){
    point = point + 8
  }else if (HR>= 100){
    point = point + 6
  }else if (HR>= 95){
    point = point + 5
  }else if (HR>= 90){
    point = point + 4
  }else if (HR>= 85){
    point = point + 3
  }else if (HR>= 80){
    point = point + 1
  }else if (HR<= 79){
    point = point + 0
  }
  
  if (COPD == 1){
    point = point +2
  } else {
    point = point+0
  }
  if (point < 79){
    outcome = 0
  } else {
    outcome = 1
  }
}
```

Then I tried to code a for loop, which looks like this :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(trainset)) {
  Systolic.BP[i] <- trainset$`Systolic blood pressure`[i]
  BUN[i] <- trainset$`Urea nitrogen`[i]
  Sodium[i]  <- trainset$`Blood sodium`[i]
  Age[i]  <- trainset$age[i]
  HR[i]  <- trainset$`heart rate`[i]
  COPD[i]  <- trainset$COPD[i]
  
  outcome.pred.gwtg[i]= m.gwtg(Systolic.BP[i], BUN[i], Sodium[i], Age[i], HR[i], COPD[i])
```

But when I actually got an error:
Error: object 'Systolic.BP' not found

I'm actually quite confused on how to code a for loop to loop through the rows and columns. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some of your data? You can just do `dput(head(trainset))` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: There are 50 variables in my dataset. This is part of the output:

Comment: structure(list(outcome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), age = c(72L, 75L, 83L, 43L, 75L, 76L
), gendera = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), BMI = c(37.58817943, 28.3124741, 26.57263379, 
83.26462934, 31.82484194, 24.26229342), hypertensive = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    atrialfibrillation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"),

Comment: The `dput` output is cutoff. You can edit your original question and paste it there. You could also just select the variables that you have in your code, as not all 90 of them are there. Also, if `Systolic.BP` is a new variable for the loop, then you would need to initialize it first.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is that the first time the loop runs, the line

```r
Systolic.BP[i] <- trainset$`Systolic blood pressure`[i]
```

Tries to write the first entry of `trainset$'Systolic blood pressure'` into the first position of a vector called `Systolic.BP`. But this vector doesn't exist yet.

If you are using the subsetting operator `[`, you need to have the vector already defined. For example, I get an error if I do:

```r
for(i in 1:10) {
   x[i] <- i
 }
#> Error: object 'x' not found
```

This is because `x` doesn't exist when I try to write to its first position. The correct way to do this loop would be

```r
x <- numeric(10)
for(i in 1:10) {
   x[i] <- i
 }
x
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It's not clear to me why you need to write each variable separately for passing to the function inside the loop anyway - you could just do:

```r
outcome.pred.gwtg <- numeric(nrow(trainset))

for (i in 1:nrow(trainset)) {
  
  outcome.pred.gwtg[i] <- m.gwtg(trainset$`Systolic blood pressure`[i], 
                                 trainset$`Urea nitrogen`[i],
                                 trainset$`Blood sodium`[i],
                                 trainset$age[i],
                                 trainset$`heart rate`[i],
                                 trainset$COPD[i])
}
```

Another option, since you are only using the new variable names inside the loop, is to do:

```
outcome.pred.gwtg <- numeric(nrow(trainset))

for (i in 1:nrow(trainset)) {
  Systolic.BP <- trainset$`Systolic blood pressure`[i]
  BUN         <- trainset$`Urea nitrogen`[i]
  Sodium      <- trainset$`Blood sodium`[i]
  Age         <- trainset$age[i]
  HR          <- trainset$`heart rate`[i]
  COPD        <- trainset$COPD[i]
  
  outcome.pred.gwtg[i]= m.gwtg(Systolic.BP, BUN, Sodium, Age, HR, COPD)
}
```

Also, note that there's no point in filling vectors this way in the first place. You can do it outside the loop:

```r
Systolic.BP <- trainset$`Systolic blood pressure`
BUN         <- trainset$`Urea nitrogen`
Sodium      <- trainset$`Blood sodium`
Age         <- trainset$age
HR          <- trainset$`heart rate`
COPD        <- trainset$COPD

outcome.pred.gwtg <- numeric(nrow(trainset))

for (i in 1:nrow(trainset)) {
outcome.pred.gwtg[i]= m.gwtg(Systolic.BP[i], BUN[i], Sodium[i], Age[i], HR[i], COPD[i])
}
```

Comment: I have a function in the previous code that returns outcome by calculating the total score of Systolic.BP, BUN, Sodium, Age, HR, COPD:
point = 0
m.gwtg = function(Systolic.BP, BUN, Sodium, Age, HR, COPD){
  if (Systolic.BP>=200){
    point = 0
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 190){
    point = 2
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 180){
    point = 4
  }
  if (BUN>=150){
    point = point + 28
  }else if (BUN>= 140){
    point = point + 27
  }{..............................
  }
  if (point < 79){
    outcome.pred.gwtg = 0
  } else {
    outcome.pred.gwtg = 1
  }
}

Comment: So when I try to loop through the trainset rows and columns, I got confused on how to loop though each row and apply this function which I coded

Answer (score 1):

Your function `m.gwtg(...)` can't find the i'th vector element Systolic.BP[i] because you apparently haven't created the vector Systolic.BP itself before.
Anyhow: you're working with a `data.frame` ("trainset"), and there's a couple of more efficient ways to do this in R.

Example (using `dplyr`):

```
library(dplyr)

trainset %>%
  rename(
    Systolic.BP = `Systolic blood pressure`,
    ## other renaming instructions
    ## of the form new_name = old_name ...
    HR = `heart rate`
  ) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate( 
    outcome.pred.gwtg = m.gwtg(Systolic.BP,
                               ## other renamed predictors ...
                               COPD)
  )
```